# Get only DOM element with several parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, tags

So, I have a SVG element in my DOM tree like this one:

```
<svg width="1679" height="1032" viewBox="-140 -86 1679 1032">
     <g>
          <path stroke="#00c8ed" stroke-opacity="1"></path>
          <path stroke="#00c8ed" stroke-opacity="1" d="M507 38L535 32L546 9L546 -23L543 -48L554"></path>
          <path stroke="#00c8ed" stroke-opacity="1"></path>
          <path stroke="#00c8ed" stroke-opacity="1"></path>
          <path stroke="#00c8ed" stroke-opacity="1" d="M407 138L1049 169L1011 332L991"></path>
          <path stroke="#A0D5ED" stroke-opacity="0.5" d="M407 138L1049 169L1011 332L991"></path>
     </g>
</svg>
```

I need to extract inner html of two last `<path>` elements with it two upper parents - `g` and `svg` - like this:

```
<svg width="1679" height="1032" viewBox="-140 -86 1679 1032">
     <g>
          <path stroke="#00c8ed" stroke-opacity="1" d="M407 138L1049 169L1011 332L991"></path>
          <path stroke="#A0D5ED" stroke-opacity="0.5" d="M407 138L1049 169L1011 332L991"></path>
     </g>
</svg>
```

Is it possible to reach it using JQuery only? Or I need to parse it like XML and then delete unneeded `<path>` tags?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Using jQuery for this task is definitely possible.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I need extract this inner HTML to convert it to image

Comment: That's good. It'd still be better if you showed your efforts so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In effect you're asking how to remove all but the last two `path` elements in the SVG. To do that you can use `slice()` and `remove()`:

```js
var $paths = $('svg path');
$paths.not($paths.slice(-2)).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="1679" height="1032" viewBox="-140 -86 1679 1032">
  <g>
    <path stroke="#00c8ed" stroke-opacity="1"></path>
    <path stroke="#00c8ed" stroke-opacity="1" d="M507 38L535 32L546 9L546 -23L543 -48L554"></path>
    <path stroke="#00c8ed" stroke-opacity="1"></path>
    <path stroke="#00c8ed" stroke-opacity="1"></path>
    <path stroke="#00c8ed" stroke-opacity="1" d="M407 138L1049 169L1011 332L991"></path>
    <path stroke="#A0D5ED" stroke-opacity="0.5" d="M407 138L1049 169L1011 332L991"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

> I don’t need to remove all unneeded  tags from tree. Just to extract two last  with them two upper parents like a string text

In this case you can clone the original SVG element, remove the `path` elements from it in memory then get the resulting HTML. Try this:

```js
var $svgClone = $('svg').clone();
var $paths = $svgClone.find('path');
$paths.not($paths.slice(-2)).remove();
var html = $svgClone[0].outerHTML;
console.log(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="1679" height="1032" viewBox="-140 -86 1679 1032">
  <g>
    <path stroke="#00c8ed" stroke-opacity="1"></path>
    <path stroke="#00c8ed" stroke-opacity="1" d="M507 38L535 32L546 9L546 -23L543 -48L554"></path>
    <path stroke="#00c8ed" stroke-opacity="1"></path>
    <path stroke="#00c8ed" stroke-opacity="1"></path>
    <path stroke="#00c8ed" stroke-opacity="1" d="M407 138L1049 169L1011 332L991"></path>
    <path stroke="#A0D5ED" stroke-opacity="0.5" d="M407 138L1049 169L1011 332L991"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added code in the script section below to retrieve the elements that you need.

Hope it helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head></head>
<body>

<svg width="1679" height="1032" viewBox="-140 -86 1679 1032">
     <g>
          <path stroke="#00c8ed" stroke-opacity="1"></path>
          <path stroke="#00c8ed" stroke-opacity="1" d="M507 38L535 32L546 9L546 -23L543 -48L554"></path>
          <path stroke="#00c8ed" stroke-opacity="1"></path>
          <path stroke="#00c8ed" stroke-opacity="1"></path>
          <path stroke="#00c8ed" stroke-opacity="1" d="M407 138L1049 169L1011 332L991"></path>
          <path stroke="#A0D5ED" stroke-opacity="0.5" d="M407 138L1049 169L1011 332L991"></path>
     </g>
</svg>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('svg g path').not('path:nth-last-child(2), path:last').remove();
    var svg = $('svg').wrap('<p/>').parent().html();
    $('svg').unwrap();
    console.log(svg);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don’t need to remove all unneeded <path> tags from tree. Just to extract two last <path> with them two upper parents like a string text

Comment: Then you can clone the svg element and follow same steps as above